# Actualizar datos ApplicationUser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, identity

tengo problemas con el siguiente método.

```
public async Task<string> EditUsuario(
            string id, 
            string userName, 
            string email, 
            string phoneNumber, 
            int accessFailedCount, 
            string concurrencyStamp,
            bool emailConfirmed, 
            bool lockoutEnabled, 
            DateTimeOffset lockoutEnd, 
            string normalizedEmail, 
            string normalizedUserName, 
            string passwordHash, 
            bool phoneNumberConfirmed, 
            string securityStamp, 
            bool twoFactorEnabled, 
            ApplicationUser applicationUser
        )
        {
            var resp = "";
            try
            {
              applicationUser = new ApplicationUser
              {
                  Id = id,
                  UserName = userName,
                  Email = email,
                  PhoneNumber = phoneNumber,
                  EmailConfirmed = emailConfirmed,
                  LockoutEnabled = lockoutEnabled,
                  LockoutEnd = lockoutEnd,
                  NormalizedEmail = normalizedEmail,
                  NormalizedUserName = normalizedUserName,
                  PasswordHash = passwordHash,
                  PhoneNumberConfirmed = phoneNumberConfirmed,
                  SecurityStamp = securityStamp,
                  TwoFactorEnabled = twoFactorEnabled,
                  AccessFailedCount = accessFailedCount,
                  ConcurrencyStamp = concurrencyStamp
              };
              //Actualizamos los datos
              _context.Update(applicationUser);
              await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
              resp = "Save";
            }
            catch
            {
              resp = "No Save";
            }
            return resp;
        }
```

Debería actualizar los datos, pero resp siempre me devuelve "No Save". No tengo ni idea de qué está fallando exactamente. ¿Alguien sabría decirme?

Un saludo y gracias

Comment: catch(Exception ex)
            {
              resp = "No Save because: " + ex.Message;
            }

Comment: Con esta línea podrás saber qué está fallanado :D

Comment: Gracias @fredyfx, acabo de probar y me sale algo como esto: No Save because: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: de nada, revisa a detalle dentro de esa variable "ex". "InnerMessage"

Comment: @loff agrega el modelo de ApplicationUser  y el que  esta creado de tu EF (entity framework)  en el cual guardas la información.

Comment: tu problema es el siguiente: te hace falta encontrar la entidad primero, y a esa entidad que has encontrado, editarla :D

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios @fredyfx bercklyn , tenéis razón, soy novato con esta plataforma y lo tenía todo prácticamente por defecto.

Comment: De nada bro, te sugiero que veas el workshop que hice hace un tiempo sobre ASP.net MVC 5 + Entity Framework + algo de JavaScript: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siempre recuerda que quieres Editar un Usuario, por lo que necesitas primero que nada tener ese usuario, en tu ejemplo estas creando uno nuevo. te pongo un ejemplo:

```
public class TuControlador : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    public TuControlador(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager){
      _userManager = userManager;
     }

[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> EditUsuario(string Id, ApplicationUser applicationUser){
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(Id);
    if(user == null){
      return NotFound();
      }
    user.Email = applicationUser.Email;
    user.PhoneNumber = applicationUser.PhoneNumber;
    ....
    try{
     await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
     return "saved";
    }
    catch{
      return "Not saved"
     }
 }
```

Si te fijas estoy haciendo uso de UserManager que viene con Identity y trae variedad de métodos ya implementados que te facilitan el trabajo con Entidades relacionadas a ella, ejemplo Usuarios, Roles. En esencia lo primero es buscar el usuario que quieres editar en la BD, de ahi el cod: (`var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(Id);`), donde el Id se pasa como parámetro dese otra vista. También si te fijas he eliminado todos los parámetros que pasabas en la acción puesto que al pasarle un ApplicationUser como parámetro ya el espera los atributos de esa clase, al no ser que tu hallas querido hacer un Bind de esa clase, lo cual seria de la siguiente manera:

```
 public async Task<string> EditUsuario(string Id,[Bind("Id,Email,PhoneNumber,UserName")] ApplicationUser applicationUser)
```

De esta forma le pasas un ApplicationUser pero no validarás todos los atributos de la clase, sino los especificados en el `[Bind("")]`

Una vez encontrado el Usuario le pasas los valores recogidos en tu form y tratas de guardar eso utilizando `_userManager.UpdateAsync(user);`

_userManager se declara de la misma forma que has declarado _context al principio de tu controlador y si le echas un vistazo a los métodos que contiene podrás ver que te ayuda en muchas cosas relacionadas con Identity. Saludos